Resize the grids via overlapping
I have the code like this ,


let isResizing = false;
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const mainbar = document.querySelector(".mainbar");
const bottombar = document.querySelector(".bottombar");
const gutter = document.querySelector(".gutter");

const resizeBottomBar = (event) => {
  if (!isResizing) return;

  const containerHeight = container.clientHeight;
  const pointerY = event.clientY;
  const mainbarHeight = Math.max(50, pointerY);
  const bottombarHeight = Math.max(50, containerHeight - pointerY);

  container.style.gridTemplateRows = `${mainbarHeight}px ${bottombarHeight}px`;
};

gutter.addEventListener("pointerdown", () => {
  isResizing = true;
  document.addEventListener("pointermove", resizeBottomBar);
  document.addEventListener("pointerup", () => {
    isResizing = false;
    document.removeEventListener("pointermove", resizeBottomBar);
  });
});
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 0.2fr;
  /* Initial sizes of mainbar and bottombar */
  height: 100vh;
}

.mainbar {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bottombar {
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

.gutter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 8px;
  /* Adjust handle size */
  cursor: row-resize;
  background-color: #888;
  z-index: 1;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="pane mainbar">
    <p>Main Content Area</p>
    <p>Main Content Area</p>
    <p>Main Content Area</p>
    <p>Main Content Area</p>
    <p>Main Content Area</p>
    <p>Main Content Area</p>

  </div>
  <div class="pane bottombar">
    <p>Bottom Bar (Resizable)</p>
    <span class="gutter"></span>
  </div>
</div>



What I need to do is slide the bottombar over the mainbar , currently its resizing the mainbar too small , Is it possible to resize the mainbar only upto 200px , but after mainbar reaches 200px , the bottombar should overlap/overlay and go over the mainbar(min height200px)  , I know this is possible via position absolute, Is it possible with just the GRID of css , thank you.
Here is the fiddle for you to play around - https://jsfiddle.net/e3Lonhdc/
P.s This is just sample , I will be having header , leftbar , navbar , rightbar , bottombar etc. I just want to know if grid can flow over another grid
I know i can completely overflow above another grid via   grid-area: 1 / 1; , but when i drag it will be halfway through 1st grid sometime.
Edit : I am expecting functionality exactly like this - https://jsfiddle.net/9kb5cn0v/ , which is made with lots of hacks and its too flickery when inspect element is opened.

Probably an XY issue. But your description is vague and too broad for me. Can you dd a drawing to show what you actually mean?

here i tried something with absolute - https://jsfiddle.net/vn6rp0og/ , but imagine bottom bar always starts from bottom.. also i need without position absolute

I am expecting functionality like this - https://jsfiddle.net/9kb5cn0v/ , which is made with lots of hacks and its too flickery when inspect element is opened.
